# Laravel 8 api post route not working well

Tags: php, laravel, api, postman, laravel-8

I just created a new laravel project to be used as API but when I create a post route into the `api.php` file it's not working when I test it with Postman.

When I try this code :

```php
Route::post('/announcement', function (Request $request) {
    return "OK";
});
```

I get "OK" in response :
[Postman result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ctukw.png)

But when I try this one :

```php
Route::post('/announcement', function (Request $request) {

    $request->validate([
        "departure" => "required",
        "destination" => "required",
        "capacity" => "required",
        "price" => "required"
    ]);

    $generated = [
        "uuid" => (string) Str::uuid()
    ];

    $a = new Announcement(array_merge($request->all(), $generated));
    
    return $a->save();
});
```

The server redirects me to the home page, I dont really understand what's happening...

Postman result : [Postman result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGE61.png)

CURL result :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='http://localhost:8000'" />

        <title>Redirecting to http://localhost:8000</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="http://localhost:8000">http://localhost:8000</a>.
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to create an other project or to clear the cache but still the same problem. I'm really stuck and I don't know what to do

Comment: `$request->validate` retrun html error code

Comment: Okay thank so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in api its better to use this validation:

```
$validatedData = Validator::make($request->all(), [
           "departure" => "required",
           "destination" => "required",
           "capacity" => "required",
           "price" => "required"
     ]);
   if ($validatedData->fails()) {
         return $validatedData->failed();
   }
```

in this case you can send any response you want but when you use `$this->validate` it manually redirects you somewhere else when validation is failed